# Visual Studio Community 2019 no compiler and no shown solutions in explorer

Tags: compiler-errors, visual-studio-2019, solution-explorer

I have problem with my Visual Studio Community 2019.
I can't see any files in my solution explorer and can't compile any new or old projects.

I tried reinstaling in few time and repairing in visual launcher, both didn't help.